# Colorbox with parent.html

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

I need a little help here as I'm still a beginner. What I'm trying to achieve is this,

main.php - a table with 2 columns and colorbox on the Name when click will have a form to edit(edit.php). And a add colorbox form(add.php) to add new entries.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" />
         <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".edit").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"90%", height:"90%", onOpen:function() { $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); }, onClosed:function() { $("body").css("overflow", "auto");}});
$(".add").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"90%", height:"90%", onOpen:function() { $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); }, onClosed:function() { $("body").css("overflow", "auto");}});
});
</script>
    <a href="add.php" class="add">Add new</a>
    <table id="tablecontent">
     <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Tel</td>
     </tr>
     <tbody id="tbody">

     </tbody>
     <tr>
      <td><a href="edit.php?id=1" class="edit">John</a></td>
      <td>1234567</td>
    </table>
```

add.php - After submitting, a new `<tr>` will be inserted into the main.php  `<tbody>`. If I just put `class="add"` it will not work, so I figured out adding cboxElement behind add, but is not working correctly

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form method="post">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" />
Tel:<input type="tel" name="tel" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
<? if($_POST){?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
window.parent.$("#tbody").html(parent.$("#tbody").html() + '<tr><td><a href="edit.php?&id=2" class="add cboxElement"><?=$_POST[name]?></a></td><td><?=$_POST[tel]?></td></tr>') ;
}); 
</script>
<? }?>
```

edit.php - a form to edit the entries by getting the id and call the database

```
<? $id = $_GET['id']; ?>
<form method="post">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" />
Tel:<input type="tel" name="tel" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The problem I have is, when a new `<tr>` is inserted into the parent(main.php) when I click the name to edit, the colorbox(edit.php) did not show exactly as per what is called in main.php; the width and the height. And when I click submit in edit.php, the colorbox just close and the new `<tr>` is gone.